# How to handle LEFT OUTER JOIN results efficiently with PHP / PDO

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

Long time answer finder, first time asker here. I tried looking for an answer to this, but either it doesn't exists (doubtful) or I just can't seem to come up with the proper terminology to search with (most likely).

I'm using PHP / PDO to get data from a MariaDB database. The database has tables with a many-to-many relationship and a junction table between them like this:

```
people            attendees           events
+----+------+     +------+------+     +----+-------------------------+
| id | name |     | p_id | e_id |     | id | name                    | 
+----+------+     +------+------+     +----+-------------------------+
|  1 | Bob  |     |    1 | 1    |     |  1 | Company Christmas party |
|  2 | Anne |     |    2 | 1    |     |  2 | Christmas party cleanup |
|  3 | John |     |    3 | 1    |     |  3 | John's birthday party   |
+----+------+     |    3 | 3    |     +----+-------------------------+
                  +------+------+
```

I'm using a LEFT OUTER JOIN to select the events and their attendees:

```
SELECT events.id, events.name, people.id, people.name
FROM events
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendees
  ON events.id = attendees.e_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN people
  ON attendees.p_id = people.id
```

Now the "problem" is that the query returns multiples of the same event for each attendee as follows:

```
+----+-------------------------+------+------+
| id | name                    | id   | name |
+----+-------------------------+------+------+
|  1 | Company Christmas party |    1 | Bob  |
|  1 | Company Christmas party |    2 | Anne |
|  1 | Company Christmas party |    3 | John |
|  2 | Christmas party cleanup | NULL | NULL |
|  3 | John's birthday party   |    3 | John |
+----+-------------------------+------+------+
```

Now I'm somewhat stuck with looping though the results. I want to create event objects from the results, but I want one event only as one object, adding attendees to it.

I could loop through my array of existing event objects and check if the id already exists when going through the resultset, but this seems a little inefficient. Is there a more elegant solution, possibly built into PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1. Slightly modify your query (now we have different names for event name and person name):

   ```
   SELECT events.id, events.name as event, people.id, people.name as person
   FROM events
   LEFT OUTER JOIN attendees
       ON events.id = attendees.e_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN people
       ON attendees.p_id = people.id
   ```
2. And parse results into array:

   ```
   //$queryResult is the result returned by your query
   while($row = $queryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $results[$row['event']][] = $row['person'];
   }
   ```

In the end, you have an associative array that stores events and people.

`print_r($results['Company Christmas party'])` will return you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bob
            [1] => Anne
            [2] => John
        )

)
```

Regarding efficiency, I don't see anything inefficient here, linear complexity.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was using fetchObject, saving the event to an array and then looping through the entire event array, comparing ids of existing events and objects of the resultset.

This is much simpler.